# SQLAlchemy ordering by count on a many to many relationship

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is a simplified example of my current models *(I'm using the [Flask SQLAlchemy extension](http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/))*:

```
like = db.Table(
    'like',
    db.Column('uid', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
    db.Column('pid', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))
)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20))

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))

    likes = db.relationship(
        'User',
        secondary = like,
        backref = db.backref('likes', lazy = 'dynamic'),
        lazy = 'dynamic'
    )
```

I'm trying to order `Post`'s by the amount of *likes* it has.

This is the query I'm basically trying to issue:

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(l.`pid`) as `likes`
FROM `posts` as p
LEFT JOIN `like` as l
    ON p.`id` = l.`pid`
GROUP BY p.`id`
ORDER BY `likes` DESC
```

I just haven't been able to get anything working on the SQLAlchemy side of things.

Thanks for any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I haven't used SQLAlchemy much so I figured I'd give it a shot. I didn't try to use your models, I just wrote some new ones (similar enough though):

```
likes = db.Table('likes',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User('%s')>" % self.username

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))

    likes = db.relationship('User', secondary = likes,
        backref = db.backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Post('%s')>" % self.title
```

You want to join the `likes` table, use `func.count` to count likes, `group_by` `Post` and then use `order_by`:

```
db.session.query(Post, func.count(likes.c.user_id).label('total'))\
 .join(likes).group_by(Post).order_by('total DESC')
```

I found the [ORM tutorial](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html) and the rest of the SQLAlchemy documentation very useful.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Few things to note though. You have an extra parenthesis at the end of the query. MySQL didn't like the `'-total'` _(`'total DESC'` works fine though)_. Also I think it may be better to just group on the id so `.group_by(Post.id)`. Lastly I had an issue with `func.count(likes)`. It was translating to an empty count _(`COUNT()`)_. Supplying a column fixed it though `func.count(likes.c.did)`. Thanks again.

Comment: @anomareh Great, glad it helps. I'll update my answer so it's (hopefully) more generically useful. I wonder if differing SQLAlchemy versions mattered here? I was using 0.7b4.

Comment: I had to add this .order_by(`text('count DESC')`)