# Flask SQLAlchemy - How to order query result by count of ForeignKey variable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm implementing blog posts type Flask app using Flask-SQLAlchemy.

I'm trying to order the blog posts based on total number of likes each blog post received. I've tried using SQLALchemy hybrid property with query `session.query(Post).order_by(Post.likes_count.desc()).all()` which is similar to solution to a question asked earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521645/sqlalchemy-order-by-function-result)

It throws error `AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Post.likes has an attribute 'count'`

Is there a way to get posts order using likes count which needs to be fed to paginate function.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120))
    likes = db.relationship('Like', backref='user',lazy='dynamic',foreign_keys='Like.user_id')
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}')"

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    likes = db.relationship('Like', backref='post', lazy='dynamic')

    @hybrid_property
    def likes_count(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"

class Like(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
```

This question is similar to [How to order by count of many-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876946/how-to-order-by-count-of-many-to-many-relationship-in-sqlalchemy?rq=1) However I was not able to get query results with `len` or `count()` method mentioned in answer/comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I would do it is by using sqlalchemy's `func` [functionality](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/functions.html), which just mirrors a SQL function. In this case, that would most likely be the following:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func

session.query(Post).join(Like).group_by(Post.id).order_by(func.count().desc()).all()
```

This query results in something like the following raw SQL (although I just tried to make it a little cleaner by not writing everything out):

```sql
SELECT post.*
FROM post
JOIN like ON like.post_id = post.id
GROUP BY post.id
ORDER BY count() desc
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked. However the result wasn't containing rows which has 0 likes. So, I had to use outerjoin instead of join to get result rows with 0 likes.  `session.query(Post).outerjoin(Like).group_by(Post.id).order_by(func.count().desc()).all()`

Comment: Good solution! Happy to help

Comment: I had to read w3school sql tutorial to understand your above expression. I was wondering, if it's possible to order the results based on function result combination of likes and time it created. This is similar to reddit hotness of a post ranking.
i.e., if I add 
```
    def hotness(self):
        return (self.likes.count() / (datetime.now() -self.date_created).days)
```

Comment: Yes, you can chain order by expressions, where it will use the second column to break ties in the first column. Something like `ORDER BY count() desc, date_posted` in SQL or `.order_by(func.count().desc(), Post.date_posted)` in SQLAlchemy. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Actually I'm looking for order the post query result by `hotness  = round((like+1)/ (post_age_in_days)**(1/2),2)` where hotness defined as property of Post class

Comment: I would define hotness as a hybrid_property, I'll append it to my answer to make it more readable

Comment: Sure. That would be really great. :)