# flask-sqlalchemy, sql count records in a relationship and then join to a users table

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

Im querying my users this way with sql:

```
select * 
from users
```

i get all the users but now i want to query how many friends they have so if i do this

i do this:

```
select count(*) 
from users inner join friendship on users.id = friendship.user
```

and i get exactly how many friends they have but now i want to add this record to the users table in order to order them by this number

is there a way to achieve this with sqlalchemy?

Comment: As you asked for sqlalchemy, its worth looking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973553/sqlalchemy-ordering-by-count-on-a-many-to-many-relationship which is a great solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select users.*, count(*) over (partition by friendship.user) 
from users inner join friendship on users.id = friendship.user
order by count
```

Comment: Thanks man althought is olved it like this:

SELECT m.*, SUM(case when f.monkey = m.id then 1 else 0 end) as friends\
FROM monkey as  m\
LEFT JOIN friendship as f ON  m.id = f.monkey\
GROUP BY m.id,  m.name\
order by friends desc