# Flask-SQLAlchemy query for count

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'am  using Flask-SQLAlchemy and i use one-to-many relationships. Two models

```
class Request(db.Model):

      id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
      r_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, index = True, default=datetime.utcnow)
      org = db.Column(db.String(120))
      dest = db.Column(db.String(120))
      buyer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('buyer.id'))
      sale_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sale.id'))
      cost = db.Column(db.Integer)
      sr = db.Column(db.Integer)
      profit = db.Column(db.Integer)

      def __repr__(self):
          return '<Request {} by {}>'.format(self.org, self.buyer_id)

class Buyer(db.Model):
      id  = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
      name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True)
      email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True)
      requests = db.relationship('Request', backref = 'buyer', lazy='dynamic')

      def __repr__(self):
          return '<Buyer {}>'.format(self.name)
```

I need to identify which Buyer has a minimum requests from all 
of the buyers.

I could do it manually by creating additional lists and put all 
requests in a lists and search for the list. But I believe there is another simple way to do it via SQLAlchemy query

Comment: You mean you need to find the one buyer with the fewest requests? That's different from a *query for count*.

Comment: What should happen if there is a tie? Say two buyers have each just one request, and all other buyers have more. Should both buyers be returned? Or just one? If so, which one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy ordering by count on a many to many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973553/sqlalchemy-ordering-by-count-on-a-many-to-many-relationship)

Comment: @vishes_shell: many-to-many and many-to-one differ quite a bit, and this question is about finding a single or a small subset of results.

Comment: next question for the OP: should buyers without **any** requests (`Buyer.requests.count() == 0`) be ignored?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: my approach is make  one test request for all buyers to exclude Buyer.request.count( ) == 0). If there is any better solutions please let me know.  If buyers has the same quantity of request it should pass the request for Buyer name == 'Leader'.

Comment: And what if there is no Buyer with a minimum request count *and* with that name?

Comment: Can you give us a small example in your post with some expected outcomes? Try to think of the different scenarios.

Comment: for example i want to identify which buyer has a minimum requests.  I try something like this      buyer_min_requests = db.session.query(Buyer, func.min(Buyer.requests)). But it is don't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a CTE (common table expression) for a select that produces buyer ids together with their request counts, so

```
buyer_id | request_count
:------- | :------------
1        | 5
2        | 3
3        | 1
4        | 1
```

You can filter here on the counts having to be greater than 0 to be listed.

You can then join the buyers table against that to produce:

```
buyer_id | buyer_name | buyer_email      | request_count
:------- | :--------- | :--------------- | :------------
1        | foo        | foo@example.com  | 5
2        | bar        | bar@example.com  | 3
3        | baz        | baz@example.com  | 1
4        | spam       | spam@example.com | 1
```

but because we are using a CTE, you can also query the CTE for the lowest count value. In the above example, that's `1`, and you can add a `WHERE` clause to the joined buyer-with-cte-counts query to filter the results down to only rows where the `request_count` value is equal to that minimum number.

The SQL query for this is

```sql
WITH request_counts AS (
    SELECT request.buyer_id AS buyer_id, count(request.id) AS request_count
    FROM request GROUP BY request.buyer_id
    HAVING count(request.id) > ?
)
SELECT buyer.*
FROM buyer
JOIN request_counts ON buyer.id = request_counts.buyer_id
WHERE request_counts.request_count = (
    SELECT min(request_counts.request_count)
    FROM request_counts
)
```

The `WITH request_counts AS (...)` defines a CTE, and it is that part that would produce the first table with `buyer_id` and `request_count`. The `request_count` table is then joined with `request` and the `WHERE` clause does the filtering on the `min(request_counts.request_count)` value.

Translating the above to Flask-SQLAlchemy code:

```
request_count = db.func.count(Request.id).label("request_count")
cte = (
    db.select([Request.buyer_id.label("buyer_id"), request_count])
    .group_by(Request.buyer_id)
    .having(request_count > 0)
    .cte('request_counts')
)
min_request_count = db.select([db.func.min(cte.c.request_count)]).as_scalar()
buyers_with_least_requests = Buyer.query.join(
    cte, Buyer.id == cte.c.buyer_id
).filter(cte.c.request_count == min_request_count).all()
```

Demo:

```
>>> __ = db.session.bulk_insert_mappings(
...     Buyer, [{"name": n} for n in ("foo", "bar", "baz", "spam", "no requests")]
... )
>>> buyers = Buyer.query.order_by(Buyer.id).all()
>>> requests = [
...     Request(buyer_id=b.id)
...     for b in [*([buyers[0]] * 3), *([buyers[1]] * 5), *[buyers[2], buyers[3]]]
... ]
>>> __ = db.session.add_all(requests)
>>> request_count = db.func.count(Request.id).label("request_count")
>>> cte = (
...     db.select([Request.buyer_id.label("buyer_id"), request_count])
...     .group_by(Request.buyer_id)
...     .having(request_count > 0)
...     .cte("request_counts")
... )
>>> buyers_w_counts = Buyer.query.join(cte, cte.c.buyer_id == Buyer.id)
>>> for buyer, count in buyers_w_counts.add_column(cte.c.request_count):
...     # print out buyer and request count for this demo
...     print(buyer, count, sep=": ")
<Buyer foo>: 3
<Buyer bar>: 5
<Buyer baz>: 1
<Buyer spam>: 1
>>> min_request_count = db.select([db.func.min(cte.c.request_count)]).as_scalar()
>>> buyers_w_counts.filter(cte.c.request_count == min_request_count).all()
[<Buyer baz>, <Buyer spam>]
```

I've also created a db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=1d25a6d83f538841c1fce2ec600dfce8), containing the same queries, to play with.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help i will try to understand your code. It will takes a time for me but i will. May be you could advise some good tutorial about complicated queries and how it need to be done. For me it's complicated i'm new in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @J_log: What I did here was use *SQL*, translated to SQLAlchemy. Master SQL first if you want to learn how to construct queries like these, the [`sql` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) has a section on tutorials and books. But don't despair, it took me a while to learn tricks like CTEs and proper aggregation and such.

Comment: @J_log: I've reworked the answer to add more explanation as to what is going on.