# SQLAlchemy how to get unmapped COUNT(*) as a result to a query?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble understanding how to get an unmapped column result (Such as COUNT(*)) to a mapped query.

I have two mapped tables like so:

```py
class Actor(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'actor'
    id: int = Column(Integer)
    name: str = Column(String)

    movies = relationship("Movie", secondary=movie_actors_association_table, back_populates="actors")


class Movie(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'movie'
    id: int = Column(Integer)
    name: str = Column(String)
    year: int = Column(Integer)

    actors = relationship("Actor", secondary=movie_actors_association_table, back_populates="actors")
```

The `movie_actors_association_table` looks like this:

```py
movie_actors_association_table = Table('movie_actors', Base.metadata,
                                       Column('movie_id', ForeignKey('movie.id'), primary_key=True),
                                       Column('actor_id', ForeignKey('actor.id'), primary_key=True)
                                       )
```

My goal is to print out the actors sorted by the number of movies they did in a certain year(or range of years) but I also want to get the count in the result. For example, if in 1999 Brad Pitt did 5 movies, Angelina Jolie did 3 and Nicolas Cage did 15 then I want the result to be something like  `(Nicolas Cage,15), (Brad Pitt,5), (Angelina Jolie,3)` for 1999.

For this, what I'm currently doing is:

```py
current_filter = Movie.year == 1999
query_movies = Query(Movie).filter(current_filter)
query_movies_id = Query(Movie.id).filter(current_filter)


def query_to_txt_stmt(query):
    """converts Query object to SQL text statement"""
    stmt = query.statement
    stmt_complied = stmt.compile(dialect=sqlite.dialect(), compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True})
    print(stmt_complied)
    return stmt_complied

stmt = text(
    f"SELECT actor.*, COUNT(*) as my_count FROM "
    f"actor JOIN movie_actors on actor.id = movie_actors.actor_id "
    f"WHERE movie_actors.movie_id IN ({query_to_txt_stmt(query_movies_id)}) "
    f"GROUP BY actor.id ORDER BY my_count DESC"
    )


final_query = Query(Actor).from_statement(stmt)
final_query.session = db.session # the session created in an offscreen db class
results = final_query.all() #query executes here, but I get all Actor objects as a result. Without the count.
```

This approach gives me the correct sorting of the actors, but I don't get the actual COUNT in the output. And I can't figure out how to add it to the results. And this is the heart of my question. How do I add an un-mapped column to the results? And is it possible to map the COUNT result onto the mapped Actor class in a temporary variable for example?

Note: I'm using the raw text query because I need to pass around the Query object as a parameter without it being attached to a `session`.But when I tried doing something like this: (Like it's suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5975375/5550624) answer.)

```py
query = Query(Actor, func.count(Actor.id).label("my_count")).join(movie_actors_association_table,movie_actors_association_table.c.actor_id == Actor.id).group_by(Actor.id).order_by(text("my_count DESC"))
```

And then giving it the session like so:

```py
query.session = db.session
query.all()
```

It would fail to run the query because the SQL it generated did not include the custom label of `my_count`. So it said "No Such Column 'my_count'"

However, if I did it on the session like so:

```py
db.session.query(Actor, func.count(Actor.id).label("my_count")).join(movie_actors_association_table,movie_actors_association_table.c.actor_id == Actor.id).group_by(Actor.id).order_by(text("my_count DESC"))
```

So if I don't use the raw text, it seems that I have to have access to the session when writing the query. And I don't want that. If someone has an idea how to not use raw text here and still maintain independence from the session I'll be happy to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
db.session.query(Actor).join(movie_actors_association_table,movie_actors_association_table.c.actor_id == Actor.id)
.with_entities(Actor.id, func.count(movie_actors_association_table.c.actor_id).label("my_count"))
.group_by(Actor.id)
.order_by(desc(literal_column("my_count")))
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. Do you know how can I filter on the count column? As in `where my_count > 10` for example?

Comment: Also, another issue is that `with_entitites` in your example, returns `Actor.id` and `my_count` by I also need the actual actor object.

Comment: If you want to filter on the count use `.having` statement, or you can filter on it like any columns

Comment: With entities you can return what ever you want, and you can check another method to return the whole object

Comment: When I replace `.with_entities(Actor.id, func.count(movie_actors_association_table.c.actor_id)` with `.with_entities(Actor, func.count(movie_actors_association_table.c.actor_id)` I get an exception saying it can't find the 'my_count' column. Yet it works just fine when it's `Actor.id`

Comment: After looking at the generated SQL it seems this is because when I put `Actor` instead of `Actor.id` SQLAlchemy is aliasing all the columns as `anon_1.column_name` it also does this for the count label `anon_1.my_count` this is why the order by `literal_column("my_count")` I'm unsure of how to fix this.